# Preventing FormsAuthentication expiry time from increasing

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have a relatively simple WebForms-based site using Forms Authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" defaultUrl="secure/home.aspx" name=".AdminSite" />
</authentication>
```

As it's not explicitly mentioned, `slidingExpiration` is set to true by default, and thus a user is not logged off as long as they're still navigating around the site.

However, I'd like a specific page to *not* increment the expiry time. Is this possible, either within `web.config` or in code? The only suggestions I've seen mention setting `slidingExpiration` to `false`, which would apply side-wide.

The authentication cookie is set using:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, False)
```

and therefore altering the authentication cookie itself isn't practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sliding expiration is achieved by the `FormsAuthentication` module by re-issuing the cookie when necessary. To prevent the sliding, you need to prevent the cookie renewal from happening.

This can be done by simply removing the `FormsAuthentication` cookie from the response.

Below is the code behind from a very simple web form. The `aspx` page has a `div` that shows the output from the `Page_Load` event.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testDiv.InnerHtml = "Hi, cookie is: " + HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value;
        testDiv.InnerHtml += "<br />";
        var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt( HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);
        testDiv.InnerHtml += "Expires: " + ticket.Expiration.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        if(Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName))
            testDiv.InnerHtml += "<br />Forms auth is trying to update the cookie in this response";

    }
    protected void Page_Prerender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName))
            Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
    }
}
```

The `Page_Prerender` event removes the `FormsAuthentication` cookie from the response if it's present, thereby preventing the sliding.

I tested this by setting the timeout for the `FormsAuthentication` to two minutes. Then I start debug and log in. Then I keep refreshing the page in question.

Since `FormsAuthentication` doesn't update the cookie unless half the expiration time has gone, what happens is that for the first minute, the page will keep showing the same encrypted cookie and the same expires time. After a bit more than one minute, the page will be reporting that `FormsAuthentication` is trying to renew the cookie. But the `Page_Prerender` removes the cookie so it doesn't get sent. After another minute you will be redirected to the login page.

Testing the same but removing the `Page_Prerender` method show that the cookie is changed and the expires time updated after about one minute.

Comment: That's an interesting way, and quite compact - I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works well, and very simple to implement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the response cookie's expiry date to the expiry date of the request cookie, effectively overwriting what the system is doing for that specific page.

Comment: Unfortunately, the cookie is session-based rather than persistent, and as a result has no expiry set.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I deviated from trying to alter the cookie or create a second cookie or override the cookie by changing the Session.Timeout. I think it may actually be easier to use a timer, using System.Timers. The methods for the timer can always be put into a separate class if you like.

```
using System.Timers;



public partial class MyPage:Page
{

    private System.Timers.Timer timer;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetTimer();
    }
    private void SetTimer()
    {
        // Interval is set in milliseconds- set as you please.
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000 * 60);

        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    // In this handler, stop the timer and call a method to clear all cookies.
    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        ClearAllCookies();
    }

    // Method to clear all cookies. There may be a simpler way to do this, you are vague about your cookies, so I supplied a clear all.

    public void ClearAllCookies()
    {
        HttpCookie cookie;
        string cookieName;
        int cookieCnt = Request.Cookies.Count;
        for(int i = 0; i < cookieCnt; i++)
        {
            cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;
            cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            // This causes the cookie to expire
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); 
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }

        Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

*Or* use a method that logs the user out. Either way, you will end the session without having to fiddle with the user's authentication for the duration of the remainder of the website, except to end it if the session times out on this particular page.

```
public void ForceLogOff(){

    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.RemoveAll();

    // Do here whatever you need to do. 
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
}
```

How you end the session is up to you. This provides you a way to override the sliding expiration issue, and set a custom timeout from within one page only.

Comment: I've clarified in the question how the authentication cookie is set; it's session-based with zero expiry, so altering the expiry time wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure why your solution is clearing out cookies though. Your solution appears to be equivalent to simply setting `slidingExpiration` to `false`, which isn't the problem I'm trying to solve - I'd just like a single page to not extend the expiry time when visited.

Comment: I will, thank you; I can see how it may apply, I'm just concerned that if the user visits another page and then returns to this one later they may get logged out immediately.